# Why am I receiving invalid transaction hashes?

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs

I am very new to this whole ethereum and web3 part. I've learned from this tutorial
[Link Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSLEz-XxGY8&t=545s) about how it is suposed to work and what information should my code deliver to me. But for some reason all the transaction addresses the code returns are wrong.

The whole thing is based on node.js and web3 and looks like this:

```
        if (block != null && block.transactions != null) {
        for (let txHash of block.transactions) {
            let tx = await this.web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash);
            console.log('Transaction found on block: ' + number);
            console.log({address: tx.from, value: this.web3.utils.fromWei(tx.value, 'ether'), timestamp: new Date()});
            console.log("\n+\n Address" + txHash + "\n+\n");
            console.log(this.web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash).then(console.log));
            
        }
    }
```

For example this is one of the returned transaction hashes, which if I check on ethereum.io comes as invalid.

> 0x254fdffeafd45f04d30936f48fdf2c5adeb9732e8bcdd6f4b5ba2b0cf31329d5

Comment: Are these transactions in public Ethereum main network or some other network? How do you determine they are "invalid"?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa . I have checked them here https://etherscan.io/tx/0x254fdffeafd45f04d30936f48fdf2c5adeb9732e8bcdd6f4b5ba2b0cf31329d5

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa also , they are on the public network. (It is using infuria)

Comment: Narrator: "They were not" 

Comment: True. They were not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was connected to the test network. I connected the code to the main network and then it worked.

So if you use infura make sure you use the mainnet!